# One app with many servers

Tags: rest, angular, http, frontend, backend

Let say I have an Angular 2 application. I need to get data from many pages by REST API. I have also node js server which communicates with database. How should I call APIs from Angular 2 app? Should I call APIs directly from Angular 2 app or through node js server? Option 1 is faster but option 2 gives me control what is going to be send to front end. Which option is better?

Option 1:

```
    Angular 2 app
    /     \      \
   /       \      ....
node      API 1   API N
server
```

Option 2:

```
Angular 2 app
     |
     |
 node server
 /       \
/    ...  \
API 1      API N
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I dont see how this directly relates to angular. This is more related to the question: do you want to use the node server as the **only** entry point for your HTTP requests or not. Your client app will just send http requests to different endpoints through a service, it doesnt care if its 1, 2 or 3 web apis behind it

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go with the node server as sort of proxy :)

Reasons:

- If you have a backend anyway, you should use it
- If something changes i.e. the urls of the apis, you can change it on the server
- You have everything in one place
- Your frontend is smaller and simpler
- You follow a clean MVC-architecture
- And lastly but I think it's quite important: You keep track of **who, called when which api**. This is very useful for security or statistics

Reasons not to do that:

- Your backend gets a little bit more complex
- You may have a little performance advantage